# UIButton color in UIScrollView is set to wrong color when scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift, uibutton

I have a UITableView with 20 rows And in every row I have 1 UIImageView, 4 UITextView and 3 UIButton.

My tablview loads perfectly, but when I scroll, some of UIBUtton shows wrong color.
for example only one of rows should have yellow UIColor, but when I scroll another unbutton in another row became yellow!

here is my code :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{

    var  cell:TimelineTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TimelineTableViewCell") as?  TimelineTableViewCell

    if (cell == nil){
        cell = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("TimelineTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? TimelineTableViewCell
    }

    cell!.nameLabel.text = self.userNameA[indexPath.row]
    cell!.screenNameLabel.text = "@" + self.screenNameA[indexPath.row]
    cell!.tweetLabel.text = self.tweetA[indexPath.row]

    cell?.avatarImage.hnk_setImageFromURL(NSURL(string:self.avatarA[indexPath.row]))
    cell?.avatarImage.layer.cornerRadius = 4
    cell?.avatarImage.layer.masksToBounds = true

        if langA[indexPath.row] == "fa" {
            cell?.tweetLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        } else if langA[indexPath.row] == "ar" {
            cell?.tweetLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Right
        }

        cell?.favButton.setTitle(favorite_countA[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)
        cell?.reTweetButton.setTitle(retweet_countA[indexPath.row], forState: .Normal)

        if favoritedA[indexPath.row] {
            cell?.favButton.setTitleColor("#FFE066".UIColor, forState: .Normal)
        }

        if retweetedA[indexPath.row] {
            cell?.reTweetButton.setTitleColor("#70B894".UIColor, forState: .Normal)
        }


    cell?.reTweetButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell?.reTweetButton.addTarget(self, action: "retweetPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    cell?.favButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    cell?.favButton.addTarget(self, action: "favPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell;
}
```

it only appear in UIButton. So what's wrong?

Comment: @FawadMasud An Array of Bool values, which is true if a tweet is already retweeted.

Comment: I would recommend to create the bool properties in custom cell and accessing them like cell.retweetedA. The problem seems to be with the index of cell when scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Use a another Identifier, TableView doesn't redraw all cells, you have to declare two CellIdentifier. One for the cell with first color and a second with the other color.